# Where can I find a primer/tour of active directory objects under the hood?

Tags: active-directory

So I was looking around under the hood of my ActiveDirectory setup (AD version for Windows Server 2008); specifically removing some stale exchange administrative group objects. And I was wondering if anyone knew of a MS article and/or third party web page which goes over some basic AD objects in ADSI edit. You know, where the user objects created in the GUI are? where the permissions objects are (if indeed they are separate objects) etc.

Comment: You really should almost _NEVER_ be using ADSI edit unless something is really broken - or in a few other cases. And if you don't already know what things are ... really really close ADSI please.

Comment: Zypher, yes I know that it is a window to some very important behind the scenes objects in the ActiveDirectory, i'm merely browsing around. How else would I "know what things are"? :-/

Comment: 98% of what is in ADSI is exposed through the normal toold, ADUC, ADDT, ADSS. go to View-> Advanced Features in ADUC to see some of the lower level stuff

Comment: Use Sysinternals ADExplorer while using a non-domain admin account.

Answer (score 5):

I like this O'Reilly book: [Active Directory: Designing, Deploying, and Running Active Directory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059652059X).